# Visual Studio C6385 warning c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I got the following warning because of the variable `a`:

> C6385: Reading invalid data from 'z': the readable size is 'a*4' bytes, but '12' bytes may be read

In addition, the `return` line is marked green in my IDE. How should I fix this?

```
int function(int a)
{
    int* z = new int[a];
    return z[2];
}
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 16.6.2.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215712/discussion-on-question-by-elmcls-visual-studio-c6385-warning-c).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you use dynamic memory allocation. My recommendation to avoid all the commented problems is to use a vector

```
int function(int a)
{
    std::vector<int> z(std::max(3, a));
    return z[2];
}
```

It will initialize the elements, clean up memory and guarantee the size. An alternative is to throw if the element doesn't exist

```
int function(int a)
{
    std::vector<int> z(a);
    return z.at(2);
}
```

or

```
int function(int a)
{
    if (a < 3) throw;
    std::vector<int> z(a);
    return z[2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out: adding
`if (a < 3) a = 3;`
will actually do the job. No warning anymore. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: This does not fix or help the memory leak so it's still broken code.

Comment: Note that it is incredibly easy to make diagnostic-free code that does not work. Good grammar does not imply a logical process.